# What would be the cmd.exe alternative to bash's set -e?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exit-code

I want to obtain the same functionaty that is offered by bash `set -e` but inside Windows batch files. Is this possible how?

Currently this allow me to exit but I don't want to add this line after each line of the batch file.

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 exit /B  %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: AFAIK what you want is not possible with batch files.

Comment: Unbelievable that it doesn't exist in cmd.exe.  That would be like having Java code with empty catch blocks everywhere!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### For Reference

```
-e   errexit
      Exit immediately if a simple command exits with a non-zero
      status, unless the command that fails is part of an until or
      while loop, part of an if statement, part of a && or || list,
      or if the command's return status is being inverted using !.
```

http://ss64.com/bash/set.html

#### This is unfortunately not possible with just a single command.

You will have to add a check after **each command** you want to exit upon error.  Instead of a whole separate line you can just use an or check `||` on the command result.

```
command || exit /b
```

This can also be simplified by putting it in a variable at the beginning.

```
set "e=|| exit /b"
command1 %e%
command2 %e%
```

Comment: You may need to use `errorlevel` and delayed expansion in some cases to make it work as expected!

Answer (score 2):

The context of the your batch file is important.  This should allow you to launch multiple files and exit on a true errorlevel.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (
"exeone"
"exetwo"
"exethree"
"exefour"
) do "%%~a" || exit /B  %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: You may need to use delayed expansion in some cases to make it work as expected!